# Reading large binary files (>2GB) with python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I am writing a program to process some binary files.
I used to use `numpy.fromfile` and everything worked fine until I came across some big binary file (>2gb) since numpy can't read them (memory problems) after trying unsuccesfully with h5py since I didn't get how to convert my files to h5 files. I was trying to use `open()`, `read()` and `struct.unpack_from`, in order to reconstruct the data as I would have done in c++.

My binary files represent 32 bit floats that are to be paired into 64bit complex.

The problem at the moment is that even if from the info I gathered `struct.unpack_from()` should return a tuple with all the datas of the specified type in the file it only returns the first element of the file:

The code:

```
f1 = open(IQ_File, 'rb')
a1 = f1.read()       
f = struct.unpack_from('f', a1)
print(f)
```

What I am expecting here is an output with the binary back to floats, however my output is only:

```
(-0.057812511920928955,)
```

-- a tuple containing only the first float of the file.

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong here.
What should I be doing differently?

Comment: `numpy.fromfile` actually should work on large binary files as well. You can set the `count` argument to tell numpy how many bytes it should read. This is useful if you want to read the file in chunks.

Comment: Actually i need to read the whole file, not in chunks, since i need it represented in a time graph.
Sadly using numpy.fromfile("myfile", np.complex64) results in:

MemoryError
*** Reference count error detected: 
an attempt was made to deallocate 14 (F) ***

Comment: It doesn't matter how you read the file. If it is too large for your memory, then you have to deal with that. Usually what you do is open only parts of it and process them in chunks. `struct` won't change that.

Comment: I don't think is a problem with memory, since open() and read() can actually access the file(so now i have the file opened and save as binary while my program is running) now what i need is to efficiently convert all the bytes into 32bit floats and the group them in complex. If i was on C or c++ my solution would have been to open and allocate it on the heap to be sure to have enough space, that is the basic, i don't know how python and numpy work underneath so i don't know where they are allocating things but i think something similar to what i would have done in c++ should be possible

Comment: Accessing/opening is not the same as reading/allocating. When you use `numpy.fromfile` and read (!) the whole file at once, your memory is flooded. My attempt would be to open, read it in chunks, convert the chunks and save the chunks consecutively into a new file. This way, your memory only handles parts of the data and not all at once.

Comment: Is there, then, any way i could possibly force it or use a different module in order to allocate it on the heap? i don't even know if it is possible at all on python since i can't use pointers. As i said, i am not experienced with it, i rarely use this language, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack/unpack format strings can have each item prefixed with a number to have that many items packed/unpacked. Just divide the data size by the size of `float` and put that number in the format:

```
nf = len(a1) // struct.calcsize('f')
f = struct.unpack(f"{nf}f", a1)
```

Mind that tuples are very ineffective way to store numeric array data in Python. On 64-bit systems (e.g., macOS) with CPython, a tuple of `N` floats uses `24+N*8` bytes (`sizeof(PyObject_VAR_HEAD)` + `N` pointers) for the tuple itself plus `N*24` bytes (`sizeof(PyObject_HEAD)` + one `double`) for the floats (stored internally as doubles), or `24+N*32` bytes in total. That's 8 times more than the size of the binary data!

A better option is to use `numpy.fromfile()` and explicitly provide the `count` and possibly `offset` arguments in order to read the file in chunks. If you need to know in advance how many floats in total are there in the file, use `os.stat()`:

```
nf = os.stat(IQ_File).st_size // struct.calcsize('f')
```

Answer (score 1):

`unpack_from('f', data)` reads a single float from `data`.  You are probably looking for

```py
for f in iter_unpack('f', a1):
    print(a1)
```

You can probably make this more efficient by reading only a small amount of the file (say, 64Kb at a time) in a separate loop.

Comment: ok i think the description on python documentation fooled me since it said:

Unpack the buffer, containing packed C structure data, according to fmt, starting at offset. Requires len(buffer[offset:]) >= calcsize(fmt).

that starting from offset i think got me wrong.

I already thought about slicing it but it won't be possible. i Think i'll try few times again and then fall back to c++. Thank you!